# Disabling Site Creation from end users, will still allow them to create sharepoint sites through creating new Office 365 groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, office-365-groups, site-creation

I am working on a SharePoint online tenant, and inside the SharePoint admin center site >> Setting page, i disable site creation as follow:-

[image]

So i thought that in my case only sharepoint admins (the user which i own), will be able to create new sharepoint sites.. but i have found that there are many sharepoint sites that have been created by end users (i think those got created when end users create new Office 365 groups). here is a site which got created by end users:-

[image]

so my questions are:

1. is there any relation between the ability for users to create new sharepoint sites (through creating Office 365 group) and disabling the site creation inside sharepoint admin center's setting page (as shown in my first pic) ??
2. How we can prevent end users from creating sites, even through creating office 365 groups?? is this something we can manage??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the setting only hides the command and does not disable the option to create sites for users. It says so in the setting in your screenshot.

And yes, whenever a group is created in Office 365 you get a SharePoint Modern Team site. And a group is created when you create a Team, Yammer Group, Staffhub group, PowerBI workspace, and maybe more.

If you really want to disable this, you need to disable group creation for all your user. See: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-who-can-create-office-365-groups-4c46c8cb-17d0-44b5-9776-005fced8e618

If that's not what you want, you could create your own governance solution or buy something of the shelve that manages group / team / site creation for you.

Comment: so now from a sharepoint perspective i already did the required actions, by hiding the create site command.. but this is not related to creating Office 365 groups.. which is being managed from a different place inside the office 365.. is this correct? So can i say that there is NOT any relation between the ability for users to create new sharepoint sites (through creating Office 365 group) and disabling the site creation inside sharepoint admin center's setting page (as shown in my first pic) ?

Comment: second point the link u provide https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-who-can-create-office-365-groups-4c46c8cb-17d0-44b5-9776-005fced8e618 looks like it is related more to Office 365 management issue (specifically Azure Active Directory ) rather than being sharepoint online management issue .. is this correct?

Comment: You have to understand that the products in Office 365 have converged and there are no strict distinctions anymore. So yes, from a SharePoint perspective you have done what you could, but you have to look at it from an Office 365 perspective.